# Using Symfony2's AccessDeniedHandlerInterface

Tags: security, authentication, symfony

I am trying to get my security stuff setup for symfony2 and I have it working so far, but now I need to do some more fancy things. I am currently using everything dealing with PreAuthentication (I use a third party component for logging in and session management). That part is working great in tandem with the JMS security bundle.

Now I am to the point when I want to catch the users that are throwing 403s so I can just forward them to the login page of the third party component that I am using. I think my best bet is to add an exception handler to the exception listener. I am looking at the [AccessDeniedHandlerInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Authorization/AccessDeniedHandlerInterface.html).

1. Is this the right direction for me to be going?
2. How do I add this handler to the exception listener?

EDIT:
I ended up doing something similar. I created a service that is prompted on the kernel.exception event. services.yml looks like this:

```
services:
   kernel.listener.accessDenied:
    class: Fully\Qualified\Namespace\Path\To\Class
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onAccessDeniedException }
```

and the class it self:

```
<?php

namespace Fully\Qualified\Namespace\Path\To;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent,
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response,
Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

class Class
{
  public function onAccessDeniedException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
  {
    $exception = $event->getException();
    //Get the root cause of the exception.
    while (null !== $exception->getPrevious()) {
      $exception = $exception->getPrevious();
    }
    if ($exception instanceof AccessDeniedException) {
      //Forward to third-party.
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This sounds about right.

Or, if you're specifically interested in AccessDeniedException you could also define `access_denied_handler` within your firewall in `security.yml`:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        my_firewall:
            # ...
            access_denied_handler: kernel.listener.access_denied.handler
            # ...
```

Then define your service in  your `services.xml` or equivalent:

```
<parameters>
    <parameter key="kernel.listener.security.class">Path\To\Your\Class</parameter>
</parameters>

<service id="kernel.listener.access_denied.handler" class="%kernel.listener.security.class%">
    <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="security.kernel_response" method="handle" />
</service>
```

The handler class:

```
use \Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authorization\AccessDeniedHandlerInterface;

class MyAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandlerInterface
{
    public function handle(Request $request, AccessDeniedException $accessDeniedException)
    {
        // do something with your exception and return Response object (plain message of rendered template)
    }
}
```

You can find complete Security reference of Symfony2 here: http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/configuration/security.html