# How to know if a request is been made to a protected url

Tags: php, symfony

i have a onKernelResponse listener.
in my code i want to know if the user request a firewalled url or not.
I want to set my var $isRequestToAProtectedUrl

```
...
if( $isAjaxRequest && !$isAuthenticated && $isRequestToAProtectedUrl){  
   $this->container->get("session")->invalidate();
   header('NOT_AUTHORIZED: 499'); //modifiy  header(must be catch in client)
   exit();
}
...
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Symfony2 Security solves authentication and authorization for you. It seems you need to create custom AccessDeniedHandler. There is a nice example here:
[Using Symfony2's AccessDeniedHandlerInterface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166930/using-symfony2s-accessdeniedhandlerinterface#9182954)