# How to debug tags and services configured in the symfony2 service container?

Tags: events, symfony, service, dependency-injection, tags

I am writing a service to handle AccessDeniedException and I found a way to solve it from [Using Symfony2's AccessDeniedHandlerInterface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166930/using-symfony2s-accessdeniedhandlerinterface)

```
 firewalls:
         secured_area:
         .....
            access_denied_handler: kernel.listener.accessDenied.handler
```

And define the service here:

```
services:
    kernel.listener.accessDenied.handler:
      class: %kernel.listener.accessDenied.handler.class%
      arguments: ["@service_container"]
      tags:
            - { name: 'kernel.event_listener', event: 'security.kernel_response', method: 'handle' }
```

But I dont know where I can find the definitions of these attributes for example **event: 'security.kernel_response'** . Where is the 'security.kernel_response' defined and where I can get the list of other events?

And for other handlers like 'access_denied_handler', how can I determine the tags for the corresponding services?

Comment: did my answer resolve your question. if yes please accept it - otherwise feel free to request further information with a comment :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Debugging the Symfony container:**

*To debug the service container please use one of the following console commands*

### Current versions (> 2.7)

#### Show all registered services

```
app/console debug:container
```

#### List ordered by tags

```
app/console debug:container --tags
```

#### Filtered by a single tag ( i.e. form.type )

```
app/console debug:container --tag=form.type
```

#### and to include private services

```
app/console debug:container --show-private
```

### Versions > 2.2 to < 2.7

#### Show all registered services

```
app/console container:debug
```

#### List ordered by tags

```
app/console container:debug --tags
```

#### Filtered by a single tag ( i.e. form.type )

```
app/console container:debug --tag=form.type
```

#### and to include private services

```
app/console container:debug --show-private
```

### Versions < 2.2

To quickly find a service / tag (or tagged services on symfony2.<2) use **grep** ( linux, osx ) or **findstr** ( windows ) with a pipe like this:

```
app/console container:debug | grep form
```

or

```
app/console container:debug | findstr form
```

Comment: When i run this command 'app/console container:debug --tags' I got a [RuntimeException] The "--tags" does not exist

Comment: What version of symfony do you use?