# How to Configure a Redirect without a custom Controller

Tags: symfony, routes

i have two roles in my application : user and Admin
i configure my access control that , the user cannot access to my page : hello , only the admin have this access: i used this code in my security.yml

```
access_control:
   - { path: ^/hello/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

when a simple user will connect in the root : hello.I have the error : access  denied:

how can i configure my app , that will redirect the simple user to the main page (or connection page) when he will want to access to the root hello.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should create kernel.listener.accessDenied?
[Using Symfony2's AccessDeniedHandlerInterface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166930/using-symfony2s-accessdeniedhandlerinterface)

Comment: to give a better answer (and my +1 on this) you have to report here the code (also because the linked-answers are strongly discouraged)

Comment: I agree on the linked-answer comment; I have tried to follow this link and its status is 404. Thus no one is able to try and consult the code.

Comment: I think stackoverflow links are allowed, here you are: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166930/using-symfony2s-accessdeniedhandlerinterface

Comment: @KarolWojciechowski edit your answer above, so I can remove the down vote. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Within the controller that handles /hello route, add the logic to redirect the user based on the role. You may implement this by adding the following lines of code within that controller

```
    if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('Route for Main page'));
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your response , in my case , i'm using fosuserbundle , where should i add this code , in which controller ?  SecurityController ???